# Why parenthesis around a SELECT change the results?

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

So, I have this Query:

```
SELECT id, name FROM artist WHERE artist.name LIKE '%feat.%'
```

From which, the results are these:

[image]

If I place parenthesis around the Query like this:

```
(SELECT id, name FROM artist WHERE artist.name LIKE '%feat.%')
```

From which, the results are these:

[image]

**The results change!** Why?
It's not like there is some kind of Order of Operations. It's one **SELECT** alone sitting there.

---

Would you like to reproduce it? Here's the link to the database's data and schema.

[DB Schema and Data](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xr2wgf7k3e7ver/db_stackoverflow.sql?dl=0)

Comment: What happens if you add "LIMIT 50" to the end of the query?

Comment: Did you verify the actual rows themselves?

Comment: @Dan Yeah, it works. But the odd thing is that when the LIMIT is outside it shows `Showing rows 0-24 (49 total, ...)` while when the LIMIT is inside the parenthesis, it shows `Showing rows 0 - -1 (49 total, ...)`. But why? And what `0 - - 1` means?

Edit: and above all, why does this happen?

Comment: I don't think its a SQL thing, it's likely an issue more specific to phpmyadmin

Comment: The table may have changed between the runs. Or, you connected to two different databases. I cannot think of a scenario where parentheses on a single query would make a difference.

Comment: If you would like to try to reproduce it, the database schema and data are in this dropbox sql file [dropbox db](https://www.dropbox.com/s/0xr2wgf7k3e7ver/db_stackoverflow.sql?dl=0)

. I want to see if this is a specific phpmyadmin version thing or if it's overall.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Since I already responded in your answer, I'll repost it for typical reasons for others to see. I neither have two databases nor the table changed between runs, since I've tested this multiple times. If you would like though to reproduce the error to see if your phpmyadmin reproduces it, I've left the link for the DB data and schema on my question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like it's a **phpmyadmin 4.6.3** bug since it's not something else.